# { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```r
tst <- data.frame(ref=c("A", "T", "C", "C", "G", "G"),
                      alt= c("AAA", "T", "A", "ATCGA", "G", "A"))
for(i in 1:nrow(tst)){
  if(tst[i,2] == "A"){
    tst <- tst[-i,]
  }
}
```

but I received this error
:

`Error in if (tst[i, 2] == "A") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Now I don't know how to solve it,
Thanks for any help

Comment: could you explain what you want to achieve? :)

Comment: What is the point of `-i` in the loop? Do you want to get rid of the line with **A** inside the second column? If it is the case `tst[tst[,2]!='A',]` solves the issue. No need a loop.

Comment: As a general rule, one should never use a negative index in loops, especially if it is for removing rows. Rather you should filter them like in the comment above by @maydin.

Comment: There might be better ways to achieve your goal instead of a loop. What is your expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `i=3`, one has `tst[i,2] == "A"`, so `tst` is transformed: `tst <- tst[-3,]`. Originally, `tst` has 6 rows, but now it has only 5 rows. And you get the 'missing value' message when `i` reaches 6, because there's no row 6 anymore.